# How to uninstall the exact LLVM and CLANG version on Linux

Tags: linux, clang, uninstallation

There are multiple LLVM versions present on some Unix nodes in my organization i.e.

**3.8, 5.0, and 6.0**

I only want to **uninstall LLVM 6.0** version without affecting the other 2 versions.
Same is the case for CLANG as well.

How can I do it?

Comment: What os?  This is really a super user or server fault question.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `sudo apt-get purge llvm-6.0 clang-6.0` to completely remove LLVM and clang from your system.
2. Optional) Use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kxstudio-team/builds` to remove the PPA from your system.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I understand Correctly, then instead of using "llvm-3.2" in the above command, I can use "llvm-6.0" if I want to remove version 6.0, right?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I did a mistake now I modified it.